# Represent boolean matrix as black&white squares in python

Tags: python, matrix, plot, draw

I have a two dimensional boolean array which I want to represent as a black&white squares on a board.

The array size is being set once during the program, but its content is being updated on every iteration.

In addition, I need the board to be interactive so the sqaures change color when the user click on them.

Is there any ready library/function I could use?

thanks :)

Comment: You could use `plt.imshow` ([docs here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) and an [example that maybe is similar to what you want do do can be found here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_dropped.html))

Comment: It works fine graphic-wise, but i forgot to mention that I need this board to be able to get user input - so if the user click on a sqaure it changes color

Comment: That's a different question. Matplotlib has [some event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) functionality but depending what you want to do maybe it is better to reformulate the question and try to provide a better answer (please, add code to better understanding what you want to do).